# What exactly is ICE when referring to the wix installer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, windows-installer

Our solution has some wix installers in it. Most of the time I don't care about these but on occasion the build fails with this sort of error:

[image]

Some Google-fu later, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840233/error-lght0301-failed-to-open-the-database) helpful article details how to suppress the error but I'd like to understand exactly what ICE is before I'd consider making this a permanent change.

All I can glean so far is that it stands for: *Internal Consistency Evaluator* but this doesn't really reveal much!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague (because there is more than one ICE test), but generally speaking the ICE tests make sure you haven't built an MSI file that will cause problems at install or maintenance time. This is the full list:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369206(v=vs.85).aspx

and in the best practices for installs it mentions the validation tests:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770(v=vs.85).aspx