# Building Wix on Visual Studio Online results in 'incorrectly registered scripting engine'

Tags: wix, azure-devops

I recently decided to try out visual studio online to automate my build. The build result should be some binaries and a wix created installer. Locally this works, however on visual studio online this results to errors:

> light.exe: Error executing ICE action 'ICE01'. The most common cause of this kind of ICE failure is an incorrectly registered scripting engine. See http://wix.sourceforge.net/faq.html#Error217 for details and how to solve this problem. The following string format was not expected by the external UI message logger: "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance.".
>
> [..]
>
> light.exe: An unexpected Win32 exception with error code 0x643 occurred: Action - 'ICE09' Fatal error during installation

The only solution I know to solve this is to give the build server administrator rights. In this case this is not possible.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Wix on Visual Studio Online? If yes, what do I need to change?

Comment: If the scripting engine is broken on your system, I would not do any development before I had this working properly. There are bound to be mysterious problems.

Comment: I don't have a solution for this yet either, BUT: Seems to happen whenever you try to automate a build task with devenv, which means, in other words, when you try to build your WiX project while you DON'T have user interactiveness. Meaning the user did not launch the IDE to build, no user input is allowed, no new dialog windows can be created etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other only alternative I know of is [to disable ICE validations during build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383275/736079):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SuppressValidation>true</SuppressValidation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I accepted your answer. Not really the solution I was looking for, but it seems to be the only working solution at the moment.