# How to fix Wix error 217 on the Build machine

Tags: build, wix

I am running a Continuous Integration Build on TFS. On one of the build step fails due to the WiX error which says :

**"Error LGHT0217: Error executing ICE action 'ICE01'. The most common cause of this kind of ICE failure is an incorrectly registered scripting engine. See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/error217/ for details and how to solve this problem. The following string format was not expected by the external UI message logger: "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance."**
'''

I have VSTS agents installed on different virtual machines. The same build works perfectly fine on the other two VM's but fails on one of the VM's. I checked with everthing possible but couldn't find the reason for this.

I have also gone through some of the previous comments on such type of error but even those did not help. Is there anything which I am misssing on the VM or something which is incorrectly installed.

PS: I am using VS 2017 and the Build agent has the administrator rights.

Comment: [If this is just one virtual, please check this first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722623/129130). Check all the answers, not just the one I point to.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul: I tried the solutions mentioned in the post.But still no luck ,I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are the VMs having the same environment and settings? You may check the solutions for error "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed." to see whether it helps you: https://www.easeus.com/resource/the-windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed.html

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT: Yes the environment and settings are same for all the VM's. That is what  bothering even more when everything is same then why it fails on of the VM. And I also checked the solution from the link and tried it before but it did not help me.

Comment: If you build your project locally on the problematic VM, how's the result?

Comment: The build is failing locally as well.

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: @Manzoor_Khazi As the build fails locally as well, the issue seems related to your VM environment, not TFS/DevOps. I'll remove tfs tags.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul: The OS is Windows 10.