# WIX ICE validation errors only in build pipeline?

Tags: azure, wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I'm facing ICE validation errors ICE 1 to 7 only on build pipeline. When I suppress the ICE errors then build is passed without any errors.
I have admin privileges for the server machine too. But still seeing the below errors. Any suggestions or solution for the below errors.Any more privileges are required? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post logs and code as images

Comment: Error LGHT0217: Error executing ICE action 'ICE02'. The most common cause of this kind of ICE failure is an incorrectly registered scripting engine. See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/error217/ for details and how to solve this problem. The following string format was not expected by the external UI message logger: "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance.". This is the error I'm facing

Comment: Did you go to this link https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/error217/ and check resources with explanation?

Comment: yeah, gone through the link you provided. But it didn't helped me. Any more suggestions?

Comment: [Maybe try to read all answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064580/wix-3-0-throws-error-217-while-being-executed-by-continuous-integration/9722623#9722623). I would check bitness issues as well (run 32-bit maybe). Also check for security software interference. There could be missing runtimes as well. Maybe see ["Generic Tricks?" section here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).

Comment: Nothing works for me

Comment: Not a perfect match, but [please skim this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707674/129130). Try the COM Registration perhaps, and the sfc.exe.